# Convert non-alphanumeric characters to unicode codes

Tags: php, character-encoding

I receive a token in this format :

```php
{"signature": "MEQCIFf4uQXQYR6fA48cHZMwR5K0bO/wsK5ygoCukmAfWslIAiAdc4kN1BEixxrreSI3W3x4a92+fFTw7/Ulqw9RuJPRzg\u003d\u003d","protocolVersion": "ECv1", "signedMessage": "{\"encryptedMessage\":\"HKdqg8pDCiAwaHmGeI+/7xIDXXCTSfK+/SERLh94NBX6l99w7vNgBenMCiaAGvO+nbHkmnaOnwMcq/DpRhFtCJuYjAGKA83UePYjleSgXp8AjTKUweXxpqNEVvexSeflHBQNcx4stvB7lhsCeW9SMhecebfkcgQyGlawBECXrsIWhfIRGHklC6KE18tlA0GfvsQLhKreWspHCxQjgiBDim6uR57aKzTzlTFGYK+IB1mMJbVFTrEeBnKOAlvdt8Nh4BH3DhrmV3HVl+Ydc9V2G6iGZ6EmPxe3QG5dC9aYGollEXieasTFZm1Bt/LQMdyHmQEd+cmdIQNfGhxzz5pWpLP9g8LuoG+8h69TYaVFY2o0FjP2vSuPqGhMlXhcWgb/gJsiAOLGkS2ZdFbhpQg3kEyS5f/h91Wuoxy08JHpFxsvzWL3skfJ5eQc/BykvHyzzxzK\",\"ephemeralPublicKey\":\"BFnxpfpfIeFLmJ/KM/GcQyhU0MBlEReejnKa71gKFnV+5N2t3WNBnaaNu02gjy7Z5d07XO5+O77Qx3abHnw5rwk\\u003d\",\"tag\":\"kbnLkGZKyDKBWQAh6AyCNL55V4SF8DiZ4PeIudtKBH0\\u003d\"}"}
```

I need to `json_decode` it, do something with it then push it back. If I `json_decode` it, I will get the `\u003d` character decoded to =, which is fine. But how do I encode it back ? I think I played with every possible conversion function in PHP and I'm fresh out of ideas.

Here's a sandbox to play around with : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b93defec84a9a6f22f5085fbb7628b5afa816d95

Answer (score 1):

In normal work you do not need to encode `=` to `\u003d` but if you must use somthing like this:

`$encoded = str_replace('=','\\u003d', $encoded);`

Note about your sandbox example:
In your example the token variable `signedMessage` is json in json
but after changes return as single json and not json in json like before changes.
maybe its fine for your application but check it

Comment: That's not a bad idea but the problem is that it doesn't account for this double escaped trap : `\\u003d`